# Judgment of Results from NIST Randomness Testing

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, randomness, passwords, nist

I am using the NIST suite to test the randomness of binary numbers and I have a 64KB dataset. I am confused with the results in `finalAnalysisReport.txt`.

I have the following questions:

1. does the test pass only if there is no "*" in both "p-value" and "proportion" columns?
   example:

| 12 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 0.108791 | 45/50 | * | NonOverlappingTemplate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

2. Does the "p-value" only need to be greater than 0.0001 to pass?
   [image]
3. If I can't set the same parameters so that all tests pass, is it allowed to run 15 separate tests?

Comment: Why such a small dataset? NIST runs better on larger datasets!

Comment: @ Maarten Bodewes♦ Thank you! I understand, but I'm limited by the size of the SRAM, do you have any other way to expand the true random number? Like writing a code or something?

Comment: If you can export it you may be able to stream it, put it into EEPROM etc.. You could also call the RNG multiple times, but I don't know if that will influence the state of the RNG; it depends on what you are trying to test in that case. I'm not familiar with your runtime environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.)  The pass/fail threshold is printed at the bottom of the `finalAnalysisReport.txt` file.  It looks like:-

> The minimum pass rate for each statistical test with the exception of
> the random excursion (variant) test is approximately = x for a sample
> size = y binary sequences.

45/50 is a fail.

2.)  No. $\alpha = 0.01$ is for the individual NIST tests. That seems reasonable given the relatively huge sample sizes.  But the final $\chi^2$ test seems completely unreasonable with $\alpha = 0.0001$.   It's almost as if NIST are encouraging poor generators to pass whereas common statistical analyses would use an $\alpha = 0.05$. Cui bono?

**But**.  I am somewhat doubtful of the NIST tests.  NIST/NSA objectives are not your objectives. And NIST are not great coders. I've just gotten:-

```
10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.000000 *    0/10   *  Universal
```

for a 1 MB test from `/dev/urandom`. Zero point zero?

3ish.)  64 kB is much too low for a reliable NIST SPS test. So I suggest you generate more entropy or use other test suites more appropriate for smaller samples. There is [ent](https://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) and it's contemporary replacement [ent3000](http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/ent3000/).